# Automatically update function input Python

Tags: python, function

I have written a function that takes in several inputs (see below)

```
def actual_triangle(B, zone, midpoint, lengths):

tri_reads_at_interval = {}
for d in range(int(zone[0]),int(zone[1]), 1):
    reads_in_ROI = {'T1':0, 'T2':0, 'T3':0, 'outside':0}
    for x,y in get_reads_from(zone, midpoint, lengths):
        c = which_triangle_equilateral(x,y,B,d)
        reads_in_ROI[c] += 1
    tri_reads_at_interval[d] = reads_in_ROI # Counts reads in each triangular regions at interval d

return tri_reads_at_interval
```

I have 32 zones and I would like the function to run automatically for each zone. B, midpoint and lengths never change. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: "What is the best way to do it?" A `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all `B`, `zone`, `midpoint`, `lengths` are defined and `zones` is a list with your zones, you can use `map`

```
results = list(map(lambda zone: actual_triangle(B, zone, midpoint, lengths), zones)
```

Or if you want a more memory friendly approach

```
for result in map(lambda zone: actual_triangle(B, zone, midpoint, lengths), zones):
    # do something with your result
```

Comment: An explicit `for` loop would be far more readable here. `for zone in list_of_zones: actual_triangle(B, zone, midpoint, lengths)`. Or even a list comprehension if OP needs the result of the function: `res = [actual_triangle(B, zone, midpoint, lengths) for zone in list_of_zones]`

Comment: Although I agree with your statement, there is still the memory overhead when comprehending the list. Provided that there are only 32 items this might not be an issue though

Comment: Then use a generator: `res = (actual_triangle(B, zone, midpoint, lengths) for zone in list_of_zones)`

Comment: @KostasPelelis - Thanks!  That solved my problem and it works really fast